# combining separate grid structures

Tags: html, layout, grid, bootstrap-5, grid-system

is it possible to put a navbar on the left side in a single container and row structure and place 4 boxes at the bottom and make a box on the right side? For example medium structure.Or do I need to create a 4-row structure? I researched the matter but could not find any information. Thank you in advance for your help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWrPB.png)
this is a container and row structure. Should I install a new row structure so that I can add a box called page 2 and page 3 under this?

Code:

```
        <div style="height: 200px;" class="col-sm-3 bg-success ">
        page1
        </div>
      
        <article style="height:1000px;" class="col-sm-9 bg-danger">
            <h1 style="text-align: center;">I'm Enes Salih Gökçek</h1>
        </article>
      
    </section>
</main>
```